# SQL Server: add values of small tables to the values of big table without losing the dimensions of the big table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2014

I have 3 tables. I want to add corresponding values from second table and third table to the first table in the picture below. Each table has an ID by which they can be matched, `...` field in the pictures. The first table has 1531 rows with an ID column and 8 other columns. This table, the top table in the pictures, is almost full of zeroes.

I have tried to join the tables in different ways but the problem is that each table has different number of rows and hence different number unique IDs. The top table has all IDs.

**Is there some convenient way to add the second table to the first table and then the third table to that result?**

[image]

**Result of Left Join as suggested [Suzena](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43711494/164148): why do the numbers not get summed up together?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method1: Joins**

```
select a.id,(a.col1 + b.col1+c.col1) as col1, (a.col2 + b.col2 + c.col2) as col2, (a.col3 + b.col3 + c.col3) as col3
from
table1 a
left join
table2 b
on a.id = b.id
left join
table3 c
on a.id = c.id;
```

**Method2: Unions**

```
select id,sum(col1) col1, sum(col2) col2, sum(col3) col3
from
(
    select id,col1,col2,col3
    from table1
    union all
    select id,col1,col2,col3
    from table2  
    union all  
    select id,col1,col2,col3
    from table3
) t
group by id
```

Let me know if you have any different criteria.

**Method 3: having different number of fields so use `NULL` or `0`**

```
SELECT
    [MID],
    SUM([KEVAT 201501-04]) AS      'KEVAT 201501-04',
    SUM([KESA 201504-06]) AS       'KESA 201504-06',
    SUM([SYKSY 201507-09]) AS      'SYKSY 201507-09',
    SUM([TALVI 201510-12]) AS      'TALVI 201510-12',
    SUM([KEVAT 201601-04]) AS      'KEVAT 201601-04',
    SUM([KESA 201604-06]) AS       'KESA 201604-06',
    SUM([SYKSY 201607-09]) AS      'SYKSY 201607-09',
    SUM([TALVI 201610-12]) AS      'TALVI 201610-12'
FROM
(

SELECT * FROM TABLE1

UNION ALL

SELECT [MID]
        ,0 AS 'KEVAT 201501-04'
        ,0 AS 'KESA 201504-06'
        ,0 AS 'SYKSY 201507-09'
        ,0 AS 'TALVI 201510-12'
        ,[KEVAT 201601-04]
        ,[KESA 201604-06]
        ,[SYKSY 201607-09]
        ,[TALVI 201610-12]
FROM TABLE2

UNION ALL

SELECT [MID]
        ,[KEVAT 201501-04]
        ,[KESA 201504-06]
        ,[SYKSY 201507-09]
        ,[TALVI 201510-12]
        ,0 AS 'KEVAT 201601-04'
        ,0 AS 'KESA 201604-06'
        ,0 AS 'SYKSY 201607-09'
        ,0 AS 'TALVI 201610-12'
  FROM TABLE3
) a
GROUP BY [MID]
```

Comment: When I do this, the numbers won't get summed up together: you can see the result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYSek.png). The tables are placed side-by-side. I want that when they match that the corresponding numbers will be summed up together: now they place all tables side-by-side.

Comment: I have edited the query for the sum and have also mentioned an alternate solution. Check that out and let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: I tried the second method and I got an error `All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.`: this is apparently because the number of columns in the tables differ. You can see that the first table has 9 columns while the second table and the third table have 5 columns. Each table has the same ID column to act as a key but the number of rows differ in each table -- where the first table has all possible IDs.

Comment: You can use NULL AS. For example: select id,col1,col2,col3,null as col4,null as col5 and so on.

Comment: Correct but here with `0` like this [here](https://pastebin.com/E7G7QKRG) (having NULL caused me type error because of some varchar issue), feel free to add this to your answer -- because this solves the question, thank you for helping -- I remixed this approach in the pastie :)

Comment: Always happy to help but What about the first approach? Did you try that too?

Comment: Yes I tried the first approach but see the updated the question. The second approach almost solved the issue. Your last comment solved it -- to the extent that I was able to do it myself, I added the solution here because you gave the insight :)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you could use an union. Something like:

```
      insert into table1(col1,col2,col3,col4)  
(select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table2 union 
select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table3)
```

The names of the columns of table2 and table3 must match. Use alias for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MERGE`

```
--Get data from table 2 and merge into table 1

MERGE Table_1 AS TARGET
USING (SELECT [ID]
  ,[KEVAT 201501-04]
  ,[KESA 201504-06]
  ,[SYKSY 201507-09]
  ,[TALVI 201510-12] FROM Table_2) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
    TARGET.[KEVAT 201501-04] = SOURCE.[KEVAT 201501-04],
    TARGET.[KESA 201504-06] = SOURCE.[KESA 201504-06],
    TARGET.[SYKSY 201507-09] = SOURCE.[SYKSY 201507-09],
    TARGET.[TALVI 201510-12] = SOURCE.[TALVI 201510-12];
GO

--Get data from table 3 and merge into table 1
MERGE Table_1 AS TARGET
USING (SELECT [ID]
  ,[KEVAT 201601-01]
  ,[KESA 201604-06]
  ,[SYKSY 201607-09]
  ,[TALVI 201610-12] FROM Table_3) AS SOURCE
ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN UPDATE SET
    TARGET.[KEVAT 201601-01] = SOURCE.[KEVAT 201601-01],
    TARGET.[KESA 201604-06] = SOURCE.[KESA 201604-06],
    TARGET.[SYKSY 201607-09] = SOURCE.[SYKSY 201607-09],
    TARGET.[TALVI 201610-12] = SOURCE.[TALVI 201610-12];
GO
```